# How to break line in textarea in laravel and then echo it by foreach loop?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

The name of my controller is ProductController, This is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'product_name' => 'required',
        'product_detail' => 'required',
        'product_image' => 'required',
        'admin_name' => 'required',
    ]);
    $product_image = $request->file('product_image');
    $new_name = rand().'.'.$product_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $product_image->move(public_path('product_image'), $new_name);
    $form_data = array(
        'product_image' => $new_name,
    );
    // Product::create($form_data);
    
    $product = Product::create([
        'product_name' => $request->input('product_name'),
        'product_detail' => $request->input('product_detail'),
        'admin_name' => $request->input('admin_name'),
        'product_image' => $new_name,
    ]);

    return redirect('products')->with('success', 'Data Added successfully.');
}
```

This is my index page where I want to echo it, I have doubt in Product_detail

```
@foreach($products as $product)
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-Interior">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4>{{$product->product_name}}</h4>
                                <p>
                                    <ul style="color: white">
                                            <li>{{$product->product_detail}}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's inbuilt function `nl2br()` or you can explode by `PHP_EOL` and then run the for loop for unordered list.

```php
<p>{!! nl2br($body) !!}<p>

<!-- OR -->

<ul>
    @foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $body) as $item)
        <li>{{ $item }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```